# how to remove extra records from the same table based on certain condition?

Tags: sql

I have a temporary table #temp that has following records:

```
col1    col2
a       11
a       12
a       13
b       5
b       8
```

I want to only keep records that have max col2, the result table should be like

```
col1    col2
a       13
b       8
```

can anybody help me to write the query without creating another temp table?

Comment: Start by writing a query that gets you the `MAX` for each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE t1
FROM dbo.test74 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.test74 t2
                  WHERE t2.col = t1.col              
                  HAVING MAX(t2.col2) = t1.col2
                  )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9dc5b/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
; WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        col1,
        col2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2 DESC) RowNumber,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2 DESC) RowRank
    FROM
        #Temp
)
DELETE
    CTE
WHERE
    RowNumber > 1
```

Here you can use either:

```
WHERE
    RowNumber > 1
```

or

```
WHERE
    RowRank > 1
```

in the delete statement. Use RowNumber if you don't want duplicates in the results. Use RowRank if you might have multiple rows for each col1 with the max col2 and you want to keep them both.

Comment: @GaolaiPeng I've changed the answer completely. The previous example wasn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Group By` clause:

```
SELECT
    colA,
    MAX(colB)as colB
FROM Tbl

GROUP BY
    ColA
```

[See FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c100/2)